# Temporal median image of multiple images

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Is there any other way to calculate the median image of multiple images, other than calculating the median for each individual pixel using `np.median(array)`?

I know there's already a [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736490/need-temporal-median-filter-using-opencv), but it is from 3 years ago, maybe anything came up.

Comment: The temporal median image is *defined* to be the pixel-wise median across the temporal image sequence. You can't compute it without, at some level, computing pixel-wise medians (unless you use some kind of approximation technique, but with something as cheap to compute as medians of a set of ordered sequences, it's hard to imagine why you'd want to). If you have some code that shows *how* this calculation is organized, we might be able to give some advice on whether it can be organized more efficiently, even though the same basic underlying operations will be present.

Comment: @Mr.F I was thinking about turning each image into an 1D array and with two  `for` cycles grab each value in that position, put them on a new 1D array to calculate the median and put the result on another 1D array, which would be the median image, and reshape it back to 2D using `np.reshape()`.
Any thoughts on a better way to do that?

Comment: `numpy` allows for vectorized calculations, so if you set up a 3D array that is like (height) x (width) x (time), then you can tell `numpy` to take the median across the 3rd axis, and it will automatically interpret that to mean the pixel-wise median. You should not express this with any for-loops, and it should involve only a single call to `median`. Because of the low-level optimizations that `numpy` implements, this will be faster than virtually any kind of by-hand implementation you try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of the way to put 3 toy images into a (height) x (width) x (number of images) array and then invoke `numpy.median` along the (number of images) axis (which will be the time axis if the images are arranged along it in temporal order).

```
In [1]: img1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [2]: img2 = np.array([[10, 6], [1, 0]])

In [3]: img3 = np.array([[8, 1], [0, 4]])

In [4]: images = np.zeros(shape=img1.shape + (3,))

In [5]: images[:,:,0] = img1

In [6]: images[:,:,1] = img2

In [7]: images[:,:,2] = img3

In [8]: images
Out[8]: 
array([[[  1.,  10.,   8.],
        [  2.,   6.,   1.]],

       [[  3.,   1.,   0.],
        [  4.,   0.,   4.]]])

In [9]: images[:,:,0]
Out[9]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])

In [10]: np.median(images, axis=2)
Out[10]: 
array([[ 8.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  4.]])
```

Lines 4-7 are conveniently taken care of by the `numpy.dstack` function. This would be equivalent:

```
images = np.dstack((img1, img2, img3))
```

and is the usual way 2D images read into a list or read sequentially from files will be appended, to grow the data structure incrementally. Although, often times it's more efficient to pre-allocate the slab of zeros and insert the data sequentially on load.

Comment: Thank you for your help optimizing my code. When you spoke about the vectorized calculation using the axis in `np.mean()` I fiddled a bit with it and eventually came up with `np.median([img1,img2,img3],axis=0)`, similar to your approach with `np.median(np.dstack((img1, img2, img3)),axis=2)`

Comment: Careful, `np.median` returns `float`s. You may want to cast it to `np.uint8` if you're processing it further with OpenCV. (e.g. `imshow`)

Comment: @TomaszGandor You have to be quite careful with that, because the median of an array of integers may not itself be an integer (since, for an even cardinality of numbers, the median will be the average of the middle two, and the average of those two integers may not itself be an integer). Casting to a integer type might be lossy in some situations where it is not acceptable, and you may instead prefer to apply rounding, or increase the bit size of your color representation.